# How do I make cpupower frequency-set not reset at boot?

Tags: cpupower

when I set cpu frequency range with this command:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-set -d 500MHz -u 2700MHz
```

the frequency range is succesfully set to these values, but when I reboot and do:

```
sudo cpupower frequency-info
```

i notice that the frequency range is set to other values.
This is the output:

```
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 500 MHz - 2.70 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.08 GHz and 1.08 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 998 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

Can anyone help me make it not reset?
Thanks!

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Without installing cpu frequency add-ons and tinkering with settings the machine should default to powersave governor and 500MHz - 2700MHz frequency 1 minute after boot.

Comment: I uninstalled cpufreq, cpufreqd, cpufrequtils and now it works. Thank you for the prompt response!